# Is it possible, in principle, for a second row homonuclear diatomic system to show a bond order of 4 in an excited state?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

Is it possible, in principle, for a second row homonuclear diatomic system to show a bond order of 4 in an excited state?  If so show the energy level diagram for such a system?

I am confused about this problem, mainly because I don't understand what it would mean for a diatomic system to be in an excited state.  Could I just move an arbitrary number of electrons from the n=2 energy level to the n=3 level?

Answer (score 1):

The normal excited state is one in which a single electron is promoted from a lower orbital into one of the anti-bonding ones. Thus the situation is initially $\cdots g^2$ for 2 electrons in a ground state orbital *g* (need not be the highest orbital but often is), and, say, after absorbing a photon of the correct energy the situation is $\cdots g^1a^1$ where *a* is an anti-bonding orbital. This combination of orbitals is called the excited state. (If the electron spin remains paired it is called a singlet excited state, if unpaired ('parallel') it is called a triplet excited state). As one electron is now in an anti-bonding orbital the molecule has overall weaker bonding. (However, the NO excited state may be an exception).

The excited state always decays back to the ground state (it in not a stationary state of the hamiltonian) with a lifetime that depends on the particular molecule or atom and between different molecules the lifetime
can have  a huge range, from less than a picosecond to several seconds.